# Cleaner output for wrapper components

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to create a wrapper component with as clean browser output as possible.

My component is defined in this HTML:

```
<div style="margin: 10px;">
  <div>
    {{ headerText }}
  </div>
  <div>
    <ng-content select="[section1]"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ng-content select="[section2]"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

This CSS file:

```
/* my-wrapper-container.component.css */
div {
  border: 4px green solid;
}
```

And this TypeScript file:

```
// my-wrapper-container.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: '[app-my-wrapper-container]',
  templateUrl: './my-wrapper-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-wrapper-container.component.css'],
})
export class MyWrapperContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('header-text') headerText: string;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

I can make use of the component the following way:

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<div header-text="Header 1" app-my-wrapper-container>
  <div section1>
    Content of section 1
  </div>
  <div section2>
    Content of section 2
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the output I have in the browser:

```
<!-- browser output -->
<!------------------ eliminate the following div ------------------>
<div _ngcontent-tet-c19="" header-text="Header 1" app-my-wrapper-container=""
     _nghost-tet-c18="" ng-reflect-header-text="Header 1">
  <div _ngcontent-tet-c18="" style="margin: 10px;">
    <div _ngcontent-tet-c18=""> Header 1 </div>
    <div _ngcontent-tet-c18="">
      <!------------------ eliminate the following div ------------------>
      <div _ngcontent-tet-c19="" section1="">
        Content of section 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-tet-c18="">
      <!------------------ eliminate the following div ------------------>
      <div _ngcontent-tet-c19="" section2="">
        Content of section 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can we make this whole implementation more elegant?

Basically, if possible, I would like to eliminate the 3 div elements which I marked (and only leave their inner content).

It would also be nice to eliminate the _ngcontent-tet-* attributes, but that's not a priority.

The proliferation of unnecessary div elements makes it difficult to migrate applications with existing CSS files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am not a 100% sure, but isn't it possible to use ng-container for this. Like:

```
<ng-container section1>
    Content of section 1
</ng-container>
```

The ng-container elements will be removed from the final DOM.

Comment: It seems to work, here is a repro: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-91wsds?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: It removes those two div elements, which is a great advancement. But it does not eliminate the one which has the header-text attribute. I have not given up on that yet.